# Pinescript: Can I turn on/off a plot series based on a value derived from just the current bar

Tags: pine-script

*Problem:*

- I have two moving average ema1, ema2
- If ema1 is greater than ema2 I **only** want to show ema1 and its historical values and hide the other.
- If ema1 is less than ema2 I **only** want to show ema2 and its historical values and hide the other.

I've tried countless approaches but having zero joy.

---

---

```
//@version=4
study("Line test")

ema1 = ema(close,5)
ema2 = ema(close,10)

var plot_ema_1 = false
var plot_ema_2 = false

if ema1[1] > ema2[1]
    plot_ema_1 := true
    plot_ema_2 := false

else
    plot_ema_1 := false
    plot_ema_2 := true  

plot(plot_ema_1 ? ema1 : na, color=color.blue, title="EMA-1", style=plot.style_line)
plot(plot_ema_2 ? ema2 : na, color=color.orange, title="EMA-2", style=plot.style_line)
```

[Picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1CIn.png)

**My real life usage is a little trickier I've realised.** 
There is actually a third/fourth variable..
correlation_to_asset1 and correlation_to_asset2  (these are 2 separate correlation coefficients).

The condition I'm looking to satisfy is

```
if (correlation_to_asset1 > correlation_to_asset2)
    display_ema1_and_all_its_historical_data 

   // ema2 needs to be completely turned off. A combined line doesn't 
   // work as it messes with the scaling.

else
    display_ema2_and_all_its_historical_data

   // ema1 needs to be completely turned off. A combined line doesn't 
   // work as it messes with the scaling.
```

Any insights on this would be greatly appreciated. We can use ema3/ema4 as the 3rd/4th variable...I just wanted to introduce some context with the mention of the cc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows 3 different methods of doing it. We prefer method #1:

```
//@version=4
study("Line test", "", true)

ema1 = ema(close,5)
ema2 = ema(close,10)

// ————— v1: plot the maximum of the 2 emas.
plotEma1 = ema1[1] > ema2[1]
c = plotEma1 ? color.blue : color.orange
mx = max(ema1, ema2)
plot(mx, color=c, title="EMA", style=plot.style_line)
plotchar(plotEma1 != plotEma1[1] ? mx : na, "Dot", "•", location.absolute, c, size = size.tiny)

// var plot_ema_1 = false
// var plot_ema_2 = false

// if ema1[1] > ema2[1]
//     plot_ema_1 := true
//     plot_ema_2 := false

// else
//     plot_ema_1 := false
//     plot_ema_2 := true  

// ————— v2: plot `na` color when the line isn't needed.
// plot(ema1, color=plot_ema_1 ? color.blue : na, title="EMA-1", style=plot.style_line)
// plot(ema2, color=plot_ema_2 ? color.orange : na, title="EMA-2", style=plot.style_line)

// ————— v3: plot using linebreak style.
// plot(plot_ema_1 ? ema1 : na, color=color.blue, title="EMA-1", style=plot.style_linebr)
// plot(plot_ema_2 ? ema2 : na, color=color.orange, title="EMA-2", style=plot.style_linebr)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate, I really appreciate the relpy. The answer perfectly solves the initial problem. I've amended the above with some additional info. Any insight would be greatly appreciated...even to tell me it's not possible at this time if that's the case.

Comment: Hi, Other than plotting with `line.new()`, there is no way to retroactively show/hide a plot on historical bars from a script, afawk.

Comment: Thanks mate, that sent me down the road to redemption with this one. Have what I need now with a number of lines stitched together.

Comment: Good then ) gl!